# is there another way than system() to execute a binary

Tags: c, linux

I develop a C code on Linux and I would like to execute a binary say `/usr/sbin/binary_program -p xxx`, Is there another way than `system()` call to execute a binary?

Comment: Did you look at the bottom of the `system` man page to see if there was anything in the "See Also" section?

Comment: What deficiencies are you hoping to address by using something other than `system()`?

Comment: What about using dll shared object and load it on runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, and in general, `system` should never be used, for at least these reasons:

- It suffers from all the dangers of shell quoting issues, so anything but a hard-coded command line is potentially dangerous.
- It is not thread-safe.
- It interferes with signal handling in the calling program.
- It provides no way to get output from the executed program except for the exit status, unless the command explicitly saves output to a file.

For executing external programs, you should use `posix_spawn`, or `fork` followed by one of the `exec`-family functions. However, if possible you should avoid dependency on external programs/commands, especially when it would be easier and less error-prone to do the work directly in your program. For example I've seen ridiculous usages like `system("sleep 1");` instead of `sleep(1);`.

Comment: One more useful replacement for `system` is `popen` but it has some of the same issues (like shell quoting) still.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the `exec*` family of functions.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execv.html

If needed to simulate the behavior of `system` you can `fork` and then call an `exec` function.

The POSIX [page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) of `system` says:

> The system() function shall behave as if a child process were created using fork(), and the child process invoked the sh utility using execl() as follows:
>
> execl(< shell path>, "sh", "-c", command, (char *)0);

Comment: Notice that `system` works by `fork`-ing and `exec`-ing later `/bin/sh -c` which is also standardized.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to realize that you can have several programs running simultaneously, and communicating thru pipes (or others [Inter Process Communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)). This is mostly possible thru a mixture of syscalls.

I strongly suggest reading [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), or some other good books explaining a lot more (than we can do in a few minutes) about various [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) involved, notably [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) and several others (perhaps [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) for multiplexing, e.g. to avoid deadlocks in circular pipes). The `system(3)` function is built above these syscalls (and `/bin/sh`)

<sup>That *Advanced Linux Programming* book has an entire chapter devoted to processes.</sup>

I also suggest to understand how a Unix command shell works. Either by studying the source code of some simple free shell (like `sash`) or at least by `strace`-ing it.

Practically speaking, [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) is more useful then [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html). You can get the output of the companion command.

Some libraries (Poco, Qt, Glib/GTK) also have powerful process management functions.

A new process is created with `fork` which is *tricky* to understand. A new program is started in the same process with `execve`.

<sup>All processes are created by `fork` (or perhaps `vfork`) except some few started magically by the kernel (`/sbin/init`, `/sbin/modprobe`, ...)</sup>